# Recover files after a reset hard from another branch

Tags: git, deployment, branch, github-pages, git-checkout

It's a common question here and I hope you can help me also. I didn't stash anything and no commit at all. I naively "ran" a tool that did the following to my GitHub:

```
git branch -f another-branch
git checkout another-branch
git reset --hard origin/my-work
git add -A .
git commit -a -m 'magical update'
git push origin another-branch --force
git checkout my-work (a few weeks ago)
```

I found pretty easy to recover Unstaged files. I just used the command:

> git checkout path/to/file

I tried a few solutions here and didn't solve the issue. I hope we can find a direct solution to this problem. So as I hope GitHub uses a temp to recover from this situation. The warning didn't happened to me because of the --force command.
[image]
Situation: Files with the same name as in my-work branch files are now replaced and dated **a few weeks ago**. The new files are already recovered with git checkout.

Comment: If the hard reset you did wiped out working directory files which you did not either save, commit, or stash, then those files are probably gone for good.  Did you save the files before doing the hard reset?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I didn't. I ran the tool without performing any git operation and the actual state is that.

Comment: Then your work may be lost.  Take this as a lesson to not do it again in the future.  Git is very robust to data lost, but only if you make your data part of Git via a commit, stash, branch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git reflog`

This should give you a local history of git actions you have done. Checking out the specific commitish from the reflog should get you to a point where the file you want still exists.

```
> git reflog
> git checkout HEAD@{reflog-index}
```

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and
other references were updated in the local repository. Reflogs are
useful in various Git commands, to specify the old value of a
reference. For example, `HEAD@{2}` means "where HEAD used to be two
moves ago", `master@{one.week.ago}` means "where master used to point
to one week ago in this local repository", and so on.

Comment: This may not help since the OP did not commit or stash anything before doing the hard reset.

Comment: Thanks,  the **git reflog** show me a clone operation performed before **git checkout another-branch**. I go back to this graph node I can see only replaced files so as it **git reset --hard origin/my-work** to a week ago.